# How to find royalty-free music

Tags: music

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find free sound effects?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2091/where-can-i-find-free-sound-effects)
>   [Where to find free music](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/5214/where-to-find-free-music)

In looking at various royalty-free music websites, I'm realizing that describing what one is after is not easy and therefore finding it even more so. You may select a category and listen to samples but it seems like you're looking for a needle in a haystack.

I'm looking for something like the one in this video: http://vimeo.com/29738192

How would one approach the task of finding something this?

Comment: also, [Where to find free music?](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/5214/where-to-find-free-music?rq=1)

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of "how to whittle it down" given that there is so much choice, as a process if there is any..

Comment: What *kind* of music are you looking for (genre, instrumental) ?

Comment: @AbdiasSoftware Something like the example above, wouldn't quite know how to categorize it

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer? Google it. There's a ton out there, you just have to start searching.

Helpful answer? Here are a few sites to get you started:

http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/freemusic.htm

http://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/index.html?collection=026&page=1

http://square-peach.com/terms.html

Other than that it's just a matter of hunting the good ones down. Just be on the lookout for them and you'll find a lot of gems on your journey throughout the intertubes.

Answer (score 1):

Listen to this track, I hope it sounds close to what you're looking for:

http://www.miksmusic.com/positive-and-upbeat-guitar-music-for-youtube-corporate-video

It's royalty-free and you can license it instantly online to use in youtube videos or corporate videos or commercials.

If you're looking for more royalty-free or legal free music check out this directory:

http://www.safemusiclist.com

Directory of safe and legal music resources for filmmakers, video producers, and game developers.

Good  luck!

Answer (score 0):

For the more contemporary stuff like in this video you can find a good selection at:

http://smartsound.com

iStockphoto supply more than photo: 
http://www.istockphoto.com/audio

And PumpAudio is well known:
http://pumpaudio.com/

I used to supply the two former here and know they have a broad spectrum, especially the last one, in genres and types.

SmartSound has lot of good stuff too and provide free tools to change mood and length of the music with just a click of a button (I'm not usually a fan of one-click-stop-shop things, but their solution works actually pretty well IMO).